# "no route to host": Peer to Peer Network between laptop and Raspberry Pi not working

Tags: 16.04, networking, ssh, ping, arp

I've been attempting to establish a peer-to-peer network between my laptop (Ubuntu 16.04.2, Codename: Xenial) and my Raspberry Pi 3 (Raspbian, Codename: Stretch, 9.1). After attempting to connect with `ssh`, I always get back a `no route to host`. I've run out of ideas on how to figure out why this does not work, and I would be ecstatic if someone found a solution. Here is what I've tried to see what the problem is.

The `/etc/network/interfaces` file in my laptop is:

```
auto enp3s0f1
iface enp3s0f1 inet static
address 192.168.10.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

For the Raspberry Pi, it's:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.10.3
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

The reason the network name for the laptop is `enp3s0f1` is because the name `eth0` does not work for Ubuntu 16.04. I have tried to change the name to `eth0` with:

```
sudo ip link set enp3s0f1 name eth0
```

But what I get back is:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy
```

I ran:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart.
```

For both the Pi and the laptop, and they were both successful.
I was able to establish a connection to each network respectively.
When I ran:

```
ssh pi@192.168.10.3
```

On the laptop, it shows:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.10.3 port 22: No route to host
```

I ran:

```
sudo service ssh status
```

For both devices, and they were both active.

I've inserted a raspberry pi wifi dongle in both the pi and the laptop, and that does not help.

I've tried:

```
ping 192.168.10.3
```

And it always shows:

```
From 192.168.10.3 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

I've tried:

```
arp -a
```

And I get:

```
? (192.168.10.3) at <incomplete> on enp3s0f1
```

I've also gone into the Ubuntu connection settings.
[image]

As you can see in the image, I selected the connection, went to IPv4 settings, clicked "Routes", and added the Pi's IP address. That did not help either.

Here is some more information that might be helpful to you all:

Laptop ifconfig:

[image: ifconfig output of Ubuntu 16.04]

Pi ifconfig:

[image: ifconfig output of Rasbperry Pi]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: How are the two devices connected? Is there a direct link between the two, a switch, or a router? Most Ethernet connectors include small lights that indicate a successful *electrical* connection to the Ethernet connector on the opposing end of the cable. Are all Ethernet connection status lights on the path between the two devices lit?

Comment: The ssh works with either an Ethernet cable or a router. However, I am trying to see if it is possible to do away with both, because my Pi is attached to a robot that will be in an environment with no internet connection.

Comment: This is my very first post ever on a stack exchange, but I apologize for my cumbersome formatting. Thank you for your instructions; I will keep them in mind if I ever post again.

Comment: Huh? That's not what you described in the question. According to the question the connection doesn't work over Ethernet and it appears that's what you want to resolve. How *else* are the two devices supposed to reach each other? Could you please **[edit]** your question to clarify what you're trying to achieve?